# Why does Power Query call Azure API Management backend URL?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, odata, powerquery, azure-api-management

I have an Azure App Service hosting an OData endpoint that is behind an Azure API Management (APIM) instance. To prevent calling the App Service directly it is protected by a certificate that only the APIM has.

When I call the APIM URL through Chrome or Postman, it behaves as expected. Just one request with no redirects or funny business, and it returns the OData root.
[Here is a Fiddler log of a request to the APIM using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVhjV.png)

However, when using the same URL as an OData source in Power Query using OData.Feed(), it returns a 301 which forwards to the backend URL, which obviously fails because that URL is protected by a certificate. [Here is a Fiddler log of a request to the APIM using Power Query in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSvIw.png)

I've configured the subscription key to be passed in the headers, but I've also tried it as a query param and it doesn't work in Power Query either way. I've also tried using an OData entity endpoint directly (to avoid the $metadata call) with no luck.

The user agent Power Query uses is Microsoft.Data.Mashup, but I haven't found any documentation about its compatibility with APIM, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typical fashion after working on this for two days, I discovered the answer right after posting on StackOverflow. I'll leave this question up in case anyone has the same issue.

The problem was that the Power Query connector automatically follows @odata.context links for metadata, and @odata.nextLink links for paging. These links still had the app service site as the host instead of the APIM host.

So a quick edit of the outbound rules in APIM was able to fix the issue

```
<outbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="backendBaseUrl" value="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.ToString() + context.Api.Path)" />
    <find-and-replace from="@("http://" + context.Request.Url.Host.ToString())" to="@((string)context.Variables["backendBaseUrl"])" />
    <find-and-replace from="@("https://" + context.Request.Url.Host.ToString())" to="@((string)context.Variables["backendBaseUrl"])" />
</outbound>
```

Here I have to rules to replace http and https URLs just in case some configuration changes.